# SQLite Query builder for creating tables in a database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Is there any method in the Android API of making the developers life easier when creating a table and fields?

Something like [SQLiteQueryBuilder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteQueryBuilder.html) that could allow for easily building `CREATE TABLE *...` statements with many fields from a String array perhaps.

Or is a raw SQL string the only way to go?